# In C# 5 what is the utility of the new async instruction

Tags: asynchronous, c#-5.0, async-await

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the async keyword exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225748/why-does-the-async-keyword-exist)

In the C# 5 – await and async combination - I understand the await instruction. But why should I write the async instruction? Shouldn't the compiler be able to automatically detect all async method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html), this was considered but rejected.

To summarize: a single-word `await` keyword would be too big of a breaking change. The choice was between a multi-word `await` (e.g., `await for`) or a keyword on the method (`async`) that would enable the `await` keyword just within that method. Explicitly marking methods `async` is easier for both humans and computers to parse, so they decided to go with the `async/await` pair.

See also [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/11/whither-async.aspx), [these blog comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx), [this Channel9 discussion](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Why-is-the-async-keyword-needed), [this forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/75493675-4a39-4958-a493-ad8a96f8a19d), and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225748/why-does-the-async-keyword-exist).