# Calling one method after another while using Async in one of the method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

I need to call `CallServiceCompleted()`  method after execution of `objMy_HelloWorldCompleted`. Currently before Execution of `objMy_HelloWorldCompleted`, CallServiceCompleted is being called.

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallServices());
    taskA.Wait();
    //CallServices();

    if(taskA.IsCompleted ) {
        CallServiceCompleted();
    }

}

private void CallServiceCompleted() {
    lblServicesCompleted.Text = "Work Completed";
}

private void CallServices() {
    myITSSEVR.myserv objMy = new myITSSEVR.myserv();
    string s = "New Line";
    objMy.HelloWorldCompleted += objMy_HelloWorldCompleted;
    objMy.HelloWorldAsync(s);
}

void objMy_HelloWorldCompleted(object sender,  myITSSEVR.HelloWorldCompletedEventArgs e) {
    string s2 = (string)e.UserState; 
    lblName.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [Page.RegisterAsyncTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask(v=vs.90).aspx) to handle click events:

```
protected void btnAsyncPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(MyMethodAsync));
}

private async Task MyMethodAsync(object sender, EventArgs e, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var sum = await GetSumAsync();
    lblMessage.Text = string.Format("Sum = {0}", sum);
}
```

[Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1722876.aspx?Asynchronous%20event%20handler%20using%20async%20keyword) to the forum thread.

And similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282711/4535033)