# JS async/await - why does await need async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Why does using `await` need its outer function to be declared `async`?

For example, why does this mongoose statement need the function it's in to return a promise?

```
async function middleware(hostname, done) {
  try {
    let team = await Teams.findOne({ hostnames: hostname.toLowerCase() }).exec();
    done(null, team);
  } catch (err) { done(err); }
}
```

I see the runtime/transpiler resolving the Teams promise to it's value and async signaling it "throws" rejected promises.

But try/catch "catches" those rejected promises, so why are async and await so tightly coupled?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "*But try/catch "catches" those rejected promises*". How is that relevant for the `async` keyword?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it necessary to have the async keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485350/1048572)?

Comment: "*why does this mongoose statement need the function it's in to return a promise?*" - how else would it be able to wait for the asynchronous result of the mongoose promise?

Comment: Here's a reason for the language design: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744179/1483977

Comment: It should have been enforced “Async all the way” like in C# but it was half baked into JS :( ... the way it was implemented in JS ends up just some text that coders learn they have to paste or it doesn't work –

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not privy to the JavaScript language design discussions, but I assume it's for the same reasons that [the](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/11/whither-async.aspx) [C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) [language](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Why-is-the-async-keyword-needed) [requires](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/75493675-4a39-4958-a493-ad8a96f8a19d) [`async`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225748/why-does-the-async-keyword-exist) (also see [my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html)).

Namely:

1. Backwards compatibility. If `await` was suddenly a new keyword everywhere, then any existing code using `await` as a variable name would break. Since `await` is a contextual keyword (activated by `async`), only code that *intends* to use `await` as a keyword will have `await` be a keyword.
2. Easier to parse. `async` makes asynchronous code easier to parse for transpilers, browsers, tools, and humans.

Comment: I don't think either of these arguments explain why using `await` requires the function to be asynchronous.
_easier to parse_ is **never** a good argument for language design. It has to be easier to learn and program, the parser is a program and should do the heavy lifting.
Backwards compatibility could be fixed by using any keyword that prevents legacy `await` symbols to stop working _without_ changing the function from synchronous to asynchronous.

Comment: There isn't really a reason why async would be required.
You can still use a synchronous function and implement your own _await_ by looping over until the Promise is resolved, effectively making the parent function and the called functions all synchronous.  
I've read on other answers that the reason is to avoid blocking the main event loop, but everything you do synchronously does that so, what's the gain?

Comment: @Petruza: You have to allow other code to run, though, or else the promise would never be resolved.

Comment: What I don't understand is all this crazyness of having promises if all we end up doing is calling all asynchronous code with await, then what's the point?

Comment: @Petruza: The goal is more maintainable code. In terms of maintainability, `await` > `then` > callbacks.

Comment: I see, but if APIs offer asynchronous code that we force into being called synchronously with await, what's the point besides maintainable code?

Comment: I mean, is `const result = await fetch(...); console.log(result)` better or more maintainable than `const result = fetchSync(...); console.log(result)`?
Imagine longer await chains.

Comment: @Petruza: Asynchronous is better than synchronous in most environments because it frees up the main thread. In the browser, synchronous code freezes the UI. On the server, synchronous code prevents other requests from being handled. If you are writing a command-line process/script, then synchronous code is OK, and async-or-sync becomes a matter of personal preference. Even in that environment, though, async allows concurrency if you need it.

Comment: So if I call `await func();` that is in fact running asynchronously, only that the calling scope is _asleep_ until the Promise is resolved?

Comment: @Petruza: I'm not sure what you mean by "asleep". `await` causes the function to return an unresolved Promise. Eventually it will return to the JS runtime, which executes a main loop of sorts that handles events.

Comment: By asleep I mean that the scope calling `await func()` blocks execution until the Promise returned by `func` is either resolved or rejected.

Comment: @Petruza: If by "scope ... blocks" you mean that local variables are kept in memory, then yes. If you mean that there's an execution stack and thread being blocked, then no.

Comment: It seems I'm not communicating well enough, what I mean is this:
https://jsfiddle.net/eLxjuk07/1
Let's imagine that timeout is fetch or any other code that takes a non trivial amount of time.

Comment: @Petruza: `await` does not block, but it does pause its method. During the `await`, other things can happen (e.g., other timeout callbacks). But the method will not continue executing until after the `await`.

Answer (score 7):

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744179/1483977 by @phaux:

> These answers all give valid arguments for why the async keyword is a
>   good thing, but none of them actually mentions the real reason why it
>   **had** to be added to the spec.
>
> The reason is that this was a valid JS pre-ES7
>
> ```
> function await(x) {
>   return 'awaiting ' + x
> }
>
> function foo() {
>   return(await(42))
> }
> ```
>
> According to your logic, would `foo()` return `Promise{42}` or
>   `"awaiting 42"`? (returning a Promise would break backward
>   compatibility)
>
> So the answer is: `await` is a regular identifier and it's only
>   treated as a keyword inside async functions, so they have to be marked
>   in some way.
>
> Fun fact: the original spec proposed more lightweight `function^ foo()
>   {}` for async syntax.

Comment: But doesn't the use of `await` require a space? I mean, is something like `var a = await foo()` could valid code if await were just a variable?

Comment: Why would foo() return 'awaiting 42'?  It is obvious by construction that it would.  Not for the actual await I would guess that return await(somePromise) would wait for some Promise to be resolved before returning the resolution.  Or at least that seems like a useful shorthand.   But actually such a delayed return IS basically a Promise.  OK, got it.

Comment: @user4052054 Yes, but `await (expressionThatEvaluatesToAPromise)` is a valid syntactic construction to await a promise, and `await (5)` is a valid way to pass the argument `5` to the user-defined function `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Because using `await` inside `middleware` function means the `middleware` function can't return a result immediately (it must wait until `await` is settled) and `middleware` function callers must wait until the promise (returned from `middleware` function) is settled.