# Puppeteer define browser and page synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

At the start of the Puppeteer tutorial, it says to do this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => 
{
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await browser.close();
})();
```

This seems odd to me as the whole thing is wrapped inside an asynchronous function. What if I want to wait until this finishes to continue?

Edit - Why this seems odd to me:
What if all my code relied on the browser, i.e., there is nothing I can do outside this async function. Then my code would look like this:

```
//nothing up here
(async () => 
{
    //EVERYTHING is in here
})();
//nothing down here
```

This seems weird because I might as well do everything synchronously instead of wrapping my entire program in an async function.

Comment: well, you can't, but the whole point of `async / await` is that you could continue before `browser.close` with wathever you want to scrape from `page`, because at that time `page` will be ready to be manipulated. However, the `async` IFFE itself will return a promise, on which you could connect a nice promise chain, if that is your question

Comment: to define a page you need a browser first ... the same way you need to open your browser first than open a page/tab inside it ... therefore you need to run them synchronously  and `async/await` is the way to do that ... perhaps `async ` keyword is confusing you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for the `async` function**

You need to wrap the code containing `await` instructions inside an `async` function for backwards compatibility reasons. Before ES7, you could use the word `await` as variable or function name, meaning this was valid code:

```js
var await = 123;
console.log(await);
```

To not mess with existing code, the `await` keyword only works inside of `async` functions, meaning to write code like `await page.goto(..)` you have to put it inside an async function like the one you are using.

**Waiting for the code to finish**

To wait until the code has finished, you can just continue after the last `await` statement like this:

```js
(async () => {
    // ...
    await browser.close();

    // continue with more code
})();
```

Comment: But why does await have to appear in an async function? is it because js is single threaded?

Comment: @JadenChaca I tried to answer that above. What is unclear? As I explained in my answer, it is for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason? That seems kind of stupid. I thought it had something to do with threading. Oh well, thanks

Comment: @JadenChaca Found a [similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44184006/5627599), confirming it. In general `async`/`await` just wraps [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It does not change the way threading works.